# Eclipse Google Web App Mandelbrot Errors:

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, servlets, web-applications

I am pretty new to Google plugins in Eclipse. When I import the mandelbrot demo:

```
/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.5/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.5/demos/mandelbrot/
```

First I got an error in war/WEB-INF/lib:

```
The GWT SDK JAR gwt-servlet.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory
```

Then I quick fix this by "Synchronize /WEB-INF/lib with SDK libraries", then the error disappeared;

Second, I run the app as Web Application, then the error in consol said:

```
-server must be followed by an argument for servletContainerLauncher[:args]
Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1
```

Can anyone help to figure out what happened? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what to do to make it work:

- Disable the "Use Google Web Toolkit" option from the "Google/Web toolkit" tab in the properties menu of the project.

Then run the project as a web application and visit the URL localhost:8888 in your browser.

I hope this works for you!